# How to dynamically load an Assembly Into My C# program, .NET Framework 4.7

Tags: c#, .net-assembly, dynamic-loading

I'm building an Excel to .bin console app using NPOI, what I'm looking to do is compare read data to to the class one, let me explain better...

If I have an Excel file  : Sample.xlxs

| _valueOne | _valueTwo |
| --- | --- |
| 0.0f | testString |

Then with my app I'll convert it into a Datatable (then serialize it) but I'll check for any error on the Excel file before I'll write the Datatable, for example in the final class that will be:

```
public class Sample
{
   public float _valueOne;
   public string _valueTwo;
}
```

I want to load this class to compare the value got from the Excel file to find some error (like is a string instead a float)

Final classes are contained in another project, so I would like to know if there is a way to "import" it.

Actually I'm using

```
        private static System.Type GetType(
        string in_assemblyPath,
        string in_className)
    {
        System.Type typeCur
            = System.Type.GetType(in_className);
        if (typeCur != null)
        {
            return typeCur;
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(in_assemblyPath + "/" + in_className + ".cs");
            try
            {

                System.Reflection.Assembly asm
                            = Assembly.LoadFrom(in_assemblyPath + "/" + in_className + ".cs");
                typeCur
                    = asm.GetType(in_className);
                if (typeCur != null)
                {
                    return typeCur;
                }

            }catch(Exception ex )
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(">>>>>>>>>>>   " + "Error On Assembly Load"+" <<<<<<<<<" );
                Debug.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
                Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                Debug.WriteLine(">>>>>>>>>>>   " + "End Error Report" + " <<<<<<<<<");
            }

        }

        return null;
    }
```

but I got an error message that say : The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to load a `.cs` file, which isn't an assembly - it's a code file that needs to be built to produce an assembly. Can you clarify your whole setup - why are you trying to take an Excel file and turn it into a datatable? Maybe some background on what this is for can help us understand what you are trying to do and how best to achieve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using visual studio: you need to go to your project, go to reference > Right Click > Add reference. In the window that appears select Project, and then select the project that contains classes. Then save.

EDIT: if you want to add it in a dynamic way, then, as @Romka suggested use something like this:

```
     var MainAssembly = Assembly.Load("yourpathtodll.dll");
     Type t = MainAssembly.GetType("Yournamespace." + filename);
     var finalobj = Activator.CreateInstance(t);
```

Then you can use reflection the get fields and properties.

Comment: thank's you for your help, actually i'm looking for a dynamic way, once compiled i want to be able to pass the folder that contains the assembly by args then it will runtime load the assembly

Comment: Use Assembly.LoadFrom but against the *.dll file, not the *.cs

Comment: If you want to use the cs, try with CSharpCompilation